# Macbook Pro with Bootcamp 5.0 - Windows crashes on return from sleep

Tags: windows-7, bsod, macbook-pro, boot-camp

My Macbook Pro (13" Mid 2012) crashes upon return from sleep when in Windows 7 (64 bit). I'm running the Bootcamp 5.0.5033 version of the drivers.

The minidump analysis is:

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time (usually 10 minutes).
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: fffffa80075db060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff80000b9c3d8, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: fffffa80087311d0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4ce7928f

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff88000f7e000 pci

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_c000000f:  FFFFF80000BA2FB0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00b9c388 fffff800`035398d2 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 fffffa80`075db060 fffff800`00b9c3d8 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00b9c390 fffff800`034d485c : fffff800`00b9c4c0 fffff800`00b9c4c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x33af0
fffff800`00b9c430 fffff800`034d46f6 : fffff800`03679f80 00000000`01954668 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable+0x6c
fffff800`00b9c4a0 fffff800`034d45de : 000003c4`b60d87d6 fffff800`00b9cb18 00000000`01954668 fffff800`03647f88 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0xc6
fffff800`00b9caf0 fffff800`034d43c7 : 00000110`924c57c1 00000110`01954668 00000110`924c57cf 00000000`00000068 : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`00b9cb90 fffff800`034c18ca : fffff800`03644e80 fffff800`03652cc0 00000000`00000002 fffff800`00000000 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`00b9cc40 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`00b9d000 fffff800`00b97000 fffff800`00b9cc00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_bcmwl664_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_bcmwl664_IMAGE_pci.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

This seems to indicate Broadcom's Wireless LAN driver is the culprit.

Comment: **I would try by removing the driver to verify your theory.**

Comment: update the driver or disable the power saving options for the device in the device manager.

Comment: Disabling power management for the Wiress LAN device would stop my laptop from sleeping. I'm looking into trying different driver versions -- mine is the latest one for Windows 7 apparently: 5.106.198.4.